# Zend Framework PDF not working - document has no pages

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf-generation, zend-pdf

My code is very simple:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"tesat.pdf\"");
$pdf1 = new Zend_Pdf();
$p1=$pdf1->newPage(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
$p1->drawLine(10, 10, 40, 40);
echo $pdf1->render();
die;
```

I have Acrobat reader v9
ZF v1.11
Error message: "This file can not be opened because it has no pages"
what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the page to the pdf:

```
$pdf1->pages[] = $p1;
```

Here's a decent tutorial on Zend_PDF
http://devzone.zend.com/article/2525

Comment: I would think `$pdf1->newPage(....)` should add the page to the array, oh well - THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

To add a page from [the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/fr/zend.pdf.pages.html), you should create the page, make your modification on it and then add it to your pdf.

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"tesat.pdf\"");
$pdf1 = new Zend_Pdf();
$p1 = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
$p1->drawLine(10, 10, 40, 40);
$pdf1->pages[] = $p1;
echo $pdf1->render();
```

should work.